# Value cannot be null error casting Generic list to F# List / Array

Tags: f#

My Code is ( using Microsoft playwright to scrape a web page )

```
let bpl = page.Locator("//tr[@title]")
let! links = 
    bpl.EvaluateAllAsync("(tr) => tr.map(element => element.getAttribute(\"title\"))") 
    |> Async.AwaitTask
let aa = links |> Seq.toArray
```

If I just run the first 2 lines - it will return what looks like a System.Collections.Generic.List of type string - this is exactly what I need.

[image]

Now I want to cast to an F# list or array - but as soon as I add the 3rd line I get an error ( Value cannot be null ) . Only the error happens before it even reaches the 3rd line.

what am I missing?

Full stack trace:

[image]

Comment: I do not see anything obviously wrong - it may be that the sequence returned by `EvalauteAllAsync` is lazy and evaluating it fully using `toArray` causes the program to fail later. But it is hard to say anything without having a reproducible snippet. Could you at least add a full stack-trace for the error?

Comment: Thanks @TomasPetricek .  I added the full stack trace - not sure how helpful that is.  the strange thing is that it doesn't actually make it to the 3rd line when it crashes - but if the 3rd line isn't there it doesn't crash

Comment: Can you try with explicitly specifying what the type should be?
`let! links = bpl.EvaluateAllAsync<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>("your expression") |> Async.AwaitTask`. I don't know playwright, but the according to the docs, evaluateAll has a generic return type, so it will infer to be whatever you specify, which is a #seq in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using unbox

```
let bpl = page.Locator("//tr[@title]")
        let! links = 
            bpl.EvaluateAllAsync("(tr) => tr.map(element => element.getAttribute(\"title\"))") 
            |> Async.AwaitTask
        let blogPagelinks  =
            unbox<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Object>> links
            |> Seq.map(fun item -> unbox<string> item)
            |> Seq.toList
```